# plot multiple processes graph in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to plot multiple processes data against each process name in the form of the line. A line represents the time the process was alive and the gap represents the time process was idle.

```
x_axis_data1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
x_axis_data2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
x_axis_data3 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

alive_for_time = 6
sleep_for_time = 2

plt.plot(x_axis_data1, "process1", dashes = [alive_for_time,  
sleep_for_time])
plt.plot(x_axis_data2, "process2", dashes = [alive_for_time, 
sleep_for_time])
plt.plot(x_axis_data3, "process3", dashes = [alive_for_time, 
sleep_for_time])


plt.show()
```

I am not sure how to plot against a string in pyplot. Now, I have this error:

```
ValueError: Illegal format string "process1"; two marker symbols
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `label` keyword, and the [`legend()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) function.

Some comments:

- `label` is a keyword that describes what string will appear when, at the end, you call the `legend()` function.
- Dashes are not a very good way to represent what you want, since they are at "graph units" (pixels), and you most probably want "data units" (time). Try to zoom the graph and you'll see that the dashes don't zoom accordingly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_axis_data1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
x_axis_data2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
x_axis_data3 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

alive_for_time = 6
sleep_for_time = 2

plt.plot(x_axis_data1, [1] * len(x_axis_data1), dashes = [alive_for_time,
sleep_for_time], label="process1")

plt.plot(x_axis_data2, [2] * len(x_axis_data2), dashes = [alive_for_time, 
sleep_for_time], label="process2")

plt.plot(x_axis_data2, [3] * len(x_axis_data3), dashes = [alive_for_time, 
sleep_for_time], label="process3")

plt.legend()


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the line width dynamically for each process? or it is fixed once initialized?

Comment: If you use a single line stylized with dashes, then yes, it is fixed. Most probably, what you want is a [LineCollection](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection), where each segment is a separate, parameterized line, most probably representing the time a process was alive.